# Aptana template color - how to change definitiion color

Tags: themes, aptana

I would like to change the color for defined variables in Aptana 3 and I can't find the right element for this (Window - Preferences - Aptana studio - Themes) .

```
define ("valid_username","Valid username");
<?php echo valid_username; ?>
```

I tried to change the color for constant element but it only affects numbers and true/false.

So, which element in Themes section is responsibile for defined variables.

Answer (score 0):

For php, I would try to adjust the color for "variable" instead of "constant". In the example:

$rated = "test";

$rated would have its color changed if you modified the theme for the "variable" element.

Answer (score 0):

The `valid_username` token after `echo` doesn't have a distinct scope in our current PHP support. It reports back a scope of `source.php source.php.embedded.block.html`, which is just the scope for anything inside a php block.

As a result you can't really target it to be colored differently. Textmate uses a scope of `source.php source.php.embedded.block.html constant.other.php`, which allows you to color it by targeting `constant`, or `constant.other`.

This is a bug, please file a ticket for us to fix this mismatch in scopes for this snippet here: http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa